# Librería TLSharp No logro que funcione C#

Tags: c#, telegram

Adjunto código que ejecuto al pulsar un botón, es un código en principio simple para poder enviar mensajes a través de C# a un canal de Telegram.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthUser(null, null);
    }

public virtual async void AuthUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int apiIidentificador = 99999;
        string apihashstring = "sadafsasfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf";            
        var client = new TelegramClient(apiIidentificador, apihashstring);
        await client.ConnectAsync();

        var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("+34999999999");
        var code = "888888"; // you can change code in debugger
        var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("+34999999999", hash, code);


        //get user dialogs

        var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
        //find channel by title
        var chat = dialogs.Chats
    .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLChannel))
    .Cast<TLChannel>()
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == "Planta");
}
```

La primera vez que ejecuto, telegram  me manda el mensaje indicándome el valor "code" cuando introduzco ese valor en mi código y vuelvo a ejecutar, es entonces cuando aparece el siguiente error:

An exception of type 'TLSharp.Core.Network.FloodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Flood prevention. Telegram now requires your program to do requests again only after 23299 seconds have passed (TimeToWait property). If you think the culprit of this problem may lie in TLSharp's implementation, open a Github issue please.

Ayuda please!!!!!

Comment: El mensaje de error dice claramente que debes esperar  23299 segundos antes de enviar otro mensaje. Posiblemente has enviado demasiados menaajes y telegram los toma como floodeo

Comment: Hola Luis,gracias por tu respuesta. No llego a recibir ningún mensaje, solo lo ejecuto una vez y aparece el mensaje. No entiendo que puede ocurrir...

Comment: Intenta abrir un "issue" en el github de la librería.